# Split 16x16 matrix in 4x4 in the same matrix

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix

Hi guys I am doing a small exercise splitting a 16x16 matrix in 4x4 chunks, creating a sort of diagonal of small matrix. I am representing the 4x4 matrix with a value of 1 and the rest with a value of 0, painting them in the big matrix itself.

This what it should look like:

```sh
"1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0"
"1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0"
"1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0"
"1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0"
"0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1"
"0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1"
"0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1"
"0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1"
"1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0"
"1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0"
"1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0"
"1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0"
"0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1"
"0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1"
"0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1"
"0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1"
```

This is what I have achieved at me moment:

[image]

The red squares is what I am missing. These 4x4 matrix has to be "1" as well.

This is code (it is in javascript but I don't really care about the language).

```js
let m = Array(16)
    .fill("0")
    .map(() => Array(16).fill("0"));

for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
        if (i % 8 < 4 && j % 8 < 4) {
            m[i][j] = "1";
        }
    }
}

m.map((a) => console.log(JSON.stringify(a + "")));
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank You in advance!

Comment: Your conditional works for the first and third rows of chunks but not for the second and fourth ones. To handle the even rows of chunks, you can modify your condition: `if ((i % 8 < 4 && j % 8 < 4) || (i % 8 >= 4 && j % 8 >= 4))`

Comment: `j&4 == i&4` should do, even `~(j ^ i) & 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try something like that: it uses even/odd comparison to determine position for "1"

```js
let m = Array(16)
    .fill("")
    .map(() => Array(16).fill(""));

for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
        let mi = parseInt(i/4);
        let mj = parseInt(j/4);
        m[i][j] = ((mi&1) == (mj&1))?"1":"0";
    }
}

m.map((a) => console.log(JSON.stringify(a + "")));
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Would it be possible to solve without the bitwise operator?

Comment: @MichalRužičkaRužička sure, just use `%2` to figure out odd/even numbers

Comment: Are you "splitting" an existing 16x16 matrix into 16 4x4 matrices or constructing a 16x16 matrix that contains 16 4x4 matrices having the desired pattern of zeroes and ones? If splitting I don't see the relevance of zeroes and ones; resulting 16 4x4 matrices would contain whatever values were in the original array. If constructing I suggest you remove the reference to splitting.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby:

```
require 'matrix'
```

```
m = Matrix.build(16, 16) { |i,j| (i/4).even? == (j/4).even? ? 1 : 0 }
```

To convert the matrix object to an array:

```
m.to_a
  #=> [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

See [Matrix::build](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-build) and [Enumerable#to_a](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a).

This should translate easily to other languages that have a matrix library, but even if such a library is not available, the clause

```
(i/4).even? == (j/4).even? ? 1 : 0
```

shows how the array can be constructed in an economic way.

---

---

Here's another way that does not use matrices.

```
a1 =  [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
a2 = a1.reverse
  #=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

```
Array.new(16) { |i| ((i/4).even? ? a1 : a2).dup }
```

See [Array::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-c-new) and [Kernel#dup](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-dup).